# 'Exploratory' SQL queries that uses one criteria to find more criteria

Tags: sql

Sorry about this dreadful title. Imagine tables like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48d921/1

Here, we run a query for all users with the name "Bob", but we are also interested in all users in the same postcode as "Bob" and also all users of the same "type" as Bob.

You can see I joined the same tables twice to achieve this. The trouble with it is it doesn't scale; the more criteria I want to "explore" the more times I have to join the same tables, making the select statement more cumbersome.

So:

- What's the best way to do this?
- Does this type of query have a name?

Comment: I don't think your SQLFiddle does what you say it does - here's my interpretation: `  
SELECT u.name, link.name 
FROM USER u
JOIN ADDRESS a on a.user=u.id
JOIN ADDRESS a1 on a1.postcode=a.postcode
JOIN USER link on link.id=a1.user
WHERE u.name="Bob"
and u.id != link.id`

Comment: Yes, missed a select out and the extra criteria, edited.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but it sounds like the sort of query patterns which are better dealt with in a non-relational database. I.e. it sounds "graphy" to me.

Comment: You might be right, I considered that. It may be the correct answer (in some cases) is to have separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer updated

```
SELECT 
FROM user
where u.name="Bob"
  OR (u.postcode in (SELECT a.postcode 
                     FROM USER u
                     JOIN ADDRESS a on a.user=u.id
                     WHERE u.name="Bob")
     )
  OR (u.type     in (SELECT ut.type 
                     FROM USER u
                     JOIN USER_TYPE ut1 on u.id=ut1.user
                     WHERE u.name="Bob")
     )
```

So you scan users table just once for each record checking the linking criteria

Comment: How would this scale to multiple "linking" criteria, at the same level as postcode and working in the same way?

Comment: Could be I don't understand your question properly. Could you create one more query adding one more "linking" cirteria

Comment: I've added another criteria. You can see the select statement is getting more confusing.

Comment: Does this type of conceptual query have a name (not the name of a select with OR, I mean does the approach to querying have a name)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know

Comment: I don't quite understand how this would work. Why is the where clause in the subquery there? We don't want to return results with the same name as Bob, just that are in the same postcode or have the same user type. This looks like it would only return Bob again in the subquery.

Comment: We scan just one table - user. For the table we leave users with name='Bob' or with the same postcode. To get postcodes of 'Bob' we run a subquery with the same filter.

Comment: Sorry - yes I think I understand now. In the case I'm using it in, the criteria for Bob is actually a join with other criteria, which makes it more complicated, but I think the same thing should work.